# Ring homomorphisms on the set of rationals that coincide on integers

Tags: ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring and let $f, g: \mathbb Q \to R$ be two ring homomorphisms such that $f|_{\mathbb Z}=g|_{\mathbb Z}.$ Then $f=g.$

I was trying to prove the above mentioned statement.
According to me there should be some extra conditions posed on the ring R such that integral domain. Am I right?

Comment: Notice that if you add $p/q$ to itself $q$ times you get $p$. How does this help?

Comment: I was trying to prove that f(1/n)=g(1/n). But I require extra condition on R.

Comment: You don't need any additional conditions. It's worth noting, though, that the kernel of $f$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Q}$, which is a field. So either $f$ is the zero map or R contains a copy of $\mathbb{Q}$. Maybe that's what's throwing you off.

Comment: To add to my comment. What happens if you multiply $f(1/n)$ and $g(1/n)$ by $n$?

Comment: @JoshKeneda Sir, in case R contains a copy of Q, then how will it help for proving f(1/n)=g(1/n)? Please elaborate.

Comment: @user45150 I understand that nf(1/n)=ng(1/n). But how does that imply that f(1/n)=g(1/n)?

Comment: Then use Josh Keneda's comment to allow you to divide by $n$.

Comment: @user45150 But how sir? Please elaborate...

Comment: If $f$ is not the zero map, the image of $f$ is a copy of $\mathbb{Q}$. Note that $f(n)=nf(1)=n\cdot 1=n$. How can you use that the image of $f$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ and the fact that $n$ is in the image?

Comment: @user45150 How can you take f(1)=1?

Comment: Ring homomorphism by definition takes $1$ to $1$

Comment: @user45150 No sir...it is not true...eg: R->R X R: x->(x,0)

Comment: Taking $1$ to $1$ is in the definition of ring homomorphism. See for instance:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_homomorphism, it seems to be standard. Perhaps you are trying to use another definition and that is the confusion?